How to programmatically scroll down or up on canvas while highlighting the labels being rendered?
I'm trying to create a program that will programmatically scroll through the canvas using buttons for up and down scrolling. Additionally, the frame that contains all the labels printed will be highlighted one by one every time a button was pressed.
The scrolling effect should not take effect when the highlighter does not reach the bottom of the view frame.
So, here's what I've tried:
import tkinter as tk

def scroll_up(event=None):
    canvas.yview_scroll(-1, 'units')
    highlight_label()

def scroll_down(event=None):
    canvas.yview_scroll(1, 'units')
    highlight_label()

def highlight_label():
    # Get the current viewable area of the canvas
    viewable_area = canvas.yview()
    
    # Calculate the center of the viewable area
    canvas_height = canvas.winfo_height()
    center = (viewable_area[0] + viewable_area[1]) / 2 * canvas_height
    
    # Find the label closest to the center and highlight it
    closest_label = min(labels, key=lambda label: abs(center - (frame.winfo_y() + label.winfo_y())))
    for label in labels:
        if label == closest_label:
            label.config(bg='yellow')  # Highlight the closest label
        else:
            label.config(bg='white')   # Reset background color

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Canvas Scroll')

# Create a canvas and a vertical scrollbar
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

# Grid and configure weight
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

# Create a frame inside the canvas
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor='nw')

# Add buttons to scroll the canvas
btn_up = tk.Button(root, text='Scroll Up', command=scroll_up)
btn_down = tk.Button(root, text='Scroll Down', command=scroll_down)
btn_up.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
btn_down.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew')

# Add content to the frame
labels = []
for i in range(50):
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=f'Label {i}')
    label.grid(row=i, column=0)
    labels.append(label)

# Update the scrollregion of the canvas
def on_frame_configure(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

frame.bind('<Configure>', on_frame_configure)

# Run the application
root.mainloop()

the problem with this code is that every time a button was pressed, both scrolling and highlighting takes place. Additionally, there was a bug that causes the highlighter skip some row(s) of labels.

Worked for me. No issue so far.

but there where times where it skips a row and the highlighter cannot be seen because it scrolls to much below the frame

I tested it. There are no skipping. Using Windows 10.

If you don't want both scrolling and highlighting happen at the same time, then why do you call canvas.yview_scroll() inside scroll_up() and scroll_down()?

For the skipping issue, you need to set the yscrollincrement option of the canvas to proper value (around the height of a label).
